# QPushButton with the QMenu won't change pressed style even after menu option was selected and menu was closed

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

When I choose an option from the menu, and the menu closes, the button still looks like it is being pressed over and won't change the style to the default state. This seems odd to me, and I would appreciate any solution to fix this issue. If it is a bug, please let me know how I can report it to the developers.

[image: How it looks]

[image: example when second button pressed]

Here is an example:

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QMenu,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class ExampleApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Main widget and layout
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        # Create a button
        self.button = QPushButton("Click for options", self)
        # Customize the pressed state for clarity
        self.button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton:pressed{background-color: #b5b5b5; border: 1px solid black;}"
        )
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        # Create a menu for the button
        self.menu = QMenu(self)
        self.option1 = self.menu.addAction("Option 1")
        self.option2 = self.menu.addAction("Option 2")

        # Attach the menu to the button
        self.button.setMenu(self.menu)

        # Create a second button for comparison
        self.button_2 = QPushButton("Second button", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_2)

        # Set main window properties
        self.setWindowTitle("PySide6 Button Menu Example")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)


# Initialize the application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = ExampleApp()
ex.show()

# Run the application
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Qt: v 6.6.1     PySide: v 6.6.1

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Home
OS Version:                10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631

Comment: The focus is correctly set, there's nothing odd to it: it's the only widget that can accept focus and it's also the last one to actually get it (buttons have a `StrongFocus` policy, clicking them automatically sets the focus), so it gets focused again as soon as the dialog is closed. Are you completely sure that what you see is *also* the hover state? Because that is only known to happen in Linux and older Qt version on macOS, not on Windows, but it *could* be a regression, so if that's the case, please report the actual Qt (not PyQt) version. Also, add another similar button for comparison.

Comment: @musicamante I've added additional button to test it but the first one with the menu still won't change the pressed style (it seems it pressed style) even if I click the second button

Comment: Please add *all* details: Qt version (not PyQt, not PySide, as they do **not** always match the actual Qt version) and OS info. Also edit your code to show the second button too, and possibly add another image that shows the difference between the two. Further testing would also help, and you should have done that in the first place: for instance, what happens if you hover again the button? or if you press it and close the menu without showing the dialog? does switching to another windows change something?

Comment: @musicamante Appreciate your feedback. I've updated the example code with information about the Qt and OS versions, added a second button, and removed the dialog to simplify the code. Could you test the updated code locally to see if you are experiencing the same issue? Currently, the button with the menu doesn't change its pressed style even when hovered or clicked again. And still retains its pressed style even when the second button is clicked, hovered, or focused. When I switch to another window the pressed style also won't change. Can you confirm if you're experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: @musicamante I've tried running the same code with PyQt5 and the button resets pressed style to default when its menu closed as intended, so I think that it's a bug.